# Controller is not getting input value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, controller, codeigniter-2

I have a input field

```
    <?php
    echo form_open('moneyexchange/borrow_first_page');  ?>
    <input id ="Amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount">
 <a type="submit" href="<?php echo base_url();?    >index.php/moneyexchange/invest_first_page">invest</a>
              </form>
```

And in codeigniter moneyexchange controller I have a function here

```
public function invest_first_page(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('header');

        $userProvidedAmount = $this->input->post("writtenamount");
        $data =  array(
        'userProvidedAmount' => $userProvidedAmount
         );
        $this->load->view("invest_firstpage", $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

But for some reason I cannot get the value from the input field in the view file to the controller, please help.
it shows that my $userPRovidedAmount is a (bool)false value. But I need to get numbers from the input variable
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link where your submit button should be. A link wont submit the form (unless there is some unseen javascript) - it will just make a regular `GET` request to the page (hence why `POST` is empty in your controller)

Change the action of your form and make the submit button a form element:

```
<?php echo form_open('moneyexchange/invest_first_page');  ?>
    <input id ="Amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
    <input type="submit" value="invest"/>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot !! I dint know that <a> links wont work on a form.

Comment: @Farhana No problem, glad i could help you

Comment: are you good with knockout js? I was trying to get this information from the controller to a observable do you have any idea?

Comment: @Farhana im afraid i dont have any experience with KnockoutJS, sorry